# Can a user get the status of the server with a simple http request?

Tags: http

I want to show the status of the server to the user every second.

For example, if the server has a status of 1, it takes 5 seconds to download a 1MB file, and if it is 0.1, it takes 50 seconds.

The most intuitive way is to send a GET request each time, but I want to avoid it as much as possible because there is too much data to be sent and received.

Sending a HEAD request has a small amount of data to be sent and received, but it has a large gap with the speed of the Api that the user actually experiences.

Is there any way I can guess at what speed to read in addition to reading content every second?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would use an HTTP or HTTPS request to verify that your service is up.

Given that your server has a high-bandwidth Internet connection, download speed will be determined by the client's Internet connection and route to your server. Therefore, trying to test bandwidth will 1) waste bandwidth that you pay for and 2) provide you with not-too-useful information.

Rethink what you want to monitor on your server. Typical metrics are CPU utilization, Free Memory, Free Disk Space, Disk I/O, etc. By tracking these metrics you will be able to determine how responsive your server will be to clients.